# is there a better way i could have written this program?

Tags: c++, performance, variables, if-statement, codeblocks

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

   int a;
   int b;
   int c;
   int d;
   int e;
   int f;

   int aa = 0;
   int bb = 0;
   int cc = 0;
   int dd = 0;
   int ee = 0;
   int ff = 0;

   const string odd = "ODD";
   const string even = "EVEN";

   cout << "enter 6 numbers " << endl;
   cin >> a;
   cin >> b;
   cin >> c;
   cin >> d;
   cin >> e;
   cin >> f;

   aa = a % 2;
   bb = b % 2;
   cc = c % 2;
   dd = d % 2;
   ee = e % 2;
   ff = f % 2;

   if(aa == 0){
           cout << even << endl;
   }else{
       cout << odd << endl;
   } 

   if(bb == 0){
           cout << even << endl;
   }else{
       cout << odd << endl;
   }

   if(cc == 0){
           cout << even << endl;
   }else{
       cout << odd << endl;
   }

   if(dd == 0){
           cout << even << endl;
   }else{
       cout << odd << endl;
   }

   if(ee == 0){
           cout << even << endl;
   }else{
       cout << odd << endl;
   }

   if(ff == 0){
           cout << even << endl;
   }else{
       cout << odd << endl;
   }
   return 0;
   }
```

for example is there a way to make it do the same thing but with less code, anything I should have included?

is there an easier way than having to write 6 if/else statements - is there a way to do all 6 in one statement or loop?

how could i improve its efficiency?

Comment: this is a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can use arrays and loops. The early chapters of your introductory book should cover these in detail.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: its my first time posting, i assumed this was the right place to post... i assumed wrong sorry.

Comment: It would probably help if you explain what you want the code to do

Comment: most of the answers are responding with answers that involve arrays. While those are perfectly correct solutions, they are c in nature and not necessarily the 'best' way to solve the problem in c++. I'd take a look at using `#include <vector>` and `std::vector<std::string>` to make your inputs list be as variable as you'd wish.

Answer (score 1):

Write this *function*:

```
void outputEvenness(int n)
{
    static const string odd = "ODD";
    static const string even = "EVEN";
    if(n % 2){
        cout << odd<< endl;
    } else {
       cout << even << endl;
    }
}
```

then call it using `outputEvenness(a);` `outputEvenness(b);` etc.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to return a boolean and then implement a simple `if/else`?

Comment: @Pravnav: Quite possibly yes. Why not post as an answer? The purpose of my answer was to introduce a *function* to the OP. Feel free to take things further.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I just started learning c++ about an hour ago, i am going to read up on functions so i understand this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should include header `<string>`if you use class std::string.

Also there is no sense to define these strings when they are used as string literals. Also instead of different variables it would be better to define only one array. The auxiliary variables are also unnecessary.

If to assume that you may not use arrays then I would write the program the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

int main()
{
   const size_t N = 6;

   int a = 0;
   int b = 0;
   int c = 0;
   int d = 0;
   int e = 0;
   int f = 0;

   const char *odd  = "ODD";
   const char *even = "EVEN";

   std::cout << "enter " << N << " numbers: ";
   std::cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e >> f;

   for ( int x : { a, b, c, d, e, f } )
   {
      if ( x % 2 == 0 )
      {
         std::cout << x << " is " << even << std::endl;
      }
      else
      {
         std::cout << x << " is " << odd << std::endl;
      }
   } 

   return 0;
}
```

If you are allowed to use arrays then the program could look as

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   const size_t N = 6;
   int a[N] = {};

   const char *odd  = "ODD";
   const char *even = "EVEN";

   std::cout << "enter " << N << " numbers: ";
   for ( int &x : a ) std::cin >> x;

   for ( int x : a )
   {
      if ( x % 2 == 0 )
      {
         std::cout << x << " is " << even << std::endl;
      }
      else
      {
         std::cout << x << " is " << odd << std::endl;
      }
   } 

   return 0;
}
```

For this simple program there is no sense to define a separate function that will check whether a number is even or odd because it is this program that is such a function.:)

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays and loops:

```
int a[6];  // Array of 6 ints
cout << "enter 6 numbers" << endl;
// Input the 6 numbers
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
     cin >> a[i];
}
// Output the results
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
     cout << a[i] << " is " << (a[i] & 1 ? "ODD" : "EVEN") << endl;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. is there any benefit from using a function over an array and loops in this case or is it all just preference?

Comment: Well one is less code, but 2nd, you can change the 6 to an int to have a variable number of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

```
int value = 0;
string response = "";
cout << "enter 6 numbers " << endl;
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    cin >> value;
    value % 2 == 0 ? response+="even\n" : response+="odd\n";
}
cout << response;
```